# Extracting specific lines in a chunk of text which contains a specific word, javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tags

I am currently have a chunk of string which actually a html source code stored in it. What I am trying to do now is to read out specific tags which I require using javascript. Can anyone help me with this, I am new to programming and I am not too sure how to go about it.

---

The problematic code:

```
if (request.readyState == 4) {
    var html_text = request.responseText;
    var parent = document.createElement('div');
    parent.innerHTML = html_code;
    var metas = parent.getElementsByTagName('meta');
    var meta;
    for (var i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
        meta = metas[i];
        alert(meta.property);
        alert(meta.content);
    }
}
```

The meta content works, but just that the meta property returned are undefined.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, and to programming in general. It so happens that your first question [has been asked before](http://goo.gl/i8h6).

Comment: @Pointy that seems a bit harsh, amigo. One little tag...

Comment: Perhaps you should convert it to an HTML tree, and then use something like XPath or getElementsByTagName()?

Comment: @Matt Ball - oh I didn't mean it to be harsh or anything; it was sincere in fact.  You beat me to the DOM answer or I would have added something like it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the DOM (Document Object Model) API. The [Mozilla Dev Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs) (*née* Mozilla Dev Center) is a great starting point an all-around reference.

- [JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide)
- [The DOM and JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_DOM_and_JavaScript)
- [Traversing an HTML table with JavaScript and DOM Interfaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/traversing_an_html_table_with_javascript_and_dom_interfaces)

---

> What I am trying to do now is to read out specific tags which I require using javascript.

```
var text = /* whatever string that contains HTML */;
```

First you need to parse the string:

```
var parent = document.createElement('div');
parent.innerHTML = text;
```

Then you can search for whatever kind of element you're looking for. Say you're looking for `<table>` elements.

```
var tables = parent.getElementsByTagName('table');
```

Now you can do whatever you need to each element found:

```
var table;
for (var i=0, len=tables.length; i<len; i++)
{
    table = tables[i];
    // do something with the element
}
```

#### Relevant API docs

- [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement)
- [`element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML)
- [`element.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName)

Comment: @Matt Ball Thanks. The solution works. But I was trying out with the meta tag instead and assigned it to alert the meta property but it turns out to be undefined. Do you know why? I am trying to filter out the contents I will require through the property.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not psychic. You'll have to provide some code. If there is specific code you're having difficulty with, you should almost always provide it. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)s are especially nice. You should probably just ask another question since it sounds like the actual problem is fairly different from the one you asked above.

Comment: @Matt Ball if (request.readyState == 4) { var html_text = request.responseText; var parent = document.createElement('div'); parent.innerHTML = html_code; var metas = parent.getElementsByTagName('meta'); var meta; for(var i=0; i < metas.length; i++) { meta = metas[i]; alert(meta.property); alert(meta.content); } } the meta content works, but just that the meta property returned are undefined. Sorry to leave these codes out in the previous post. Hope this code can make things clearer. The meta tags does contains property.

Comment: Please don't code dump into comments, it's impossible to read. I've edited the code into your question. What is the content of the `<meta>` element, and what are you expected `meta.property` to contain? `meta.property` is not a property of the `meta` element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/meta

Comment: i think the meta.getAttribute('property') will solve the issue. thanks anyway.

Comment: @simplified: `getAttribute` is the problem, did you see my answer with jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Attributes of XML nodes are not readily available as DOM object properties. Use `getAttribute`

**Sample:** http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/6Pdmw/

```
var node = document.createElement('div');
node.innerHTML = "<meta property='prop1' content='cont1'>"+
                 "<meta property='prop2' content='cont2'>";
var metas = node.getElementsByTagName('meta');    
for (var i = 0; i < metas.length; i++) {
    var meta = metas[i];
    alert(meta.getAttribute("property"));
    alert(meta.getAttribute("content"));
}
```